# No more endpoints in the endpoint mapper

Tags: windows, domain, thin-client, rpc, windows-xp

I was just transferred to a new factory and there is this issue that keeps popping up and the error says "There are no more endpoints in the endpoint mapper." This error occurs when trying to rejoin a computer to a domain. We have these XP embedded thin clients and they are the only machines that have problems. Has anyone else ever seen this issue? I've tried staging the computer in AD after deleting the object and no luck, I've also tried restarting the RPC services but that yields nothing either. The one thing that I find strange is that these machines dont have RPC Enpoint mapper they only have RPC and RPC Locator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had this issue with a ISA 2006 box that it couldn't connect to a specific forest in a 2 way forest full-trust.

We never did find a solution but now believe it was down to Symantec endpoint firewall that was installed and some of the flood DoS protection built into ISA needed disabling.
    (It was one of the engineers installed the endpoint protection for AV etc but didn't think to disable the firewall aspect #fail)
In the end we got fed up of troubleshooting that we rebuilt the box and left it bare minimum

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately thats what I've been doing to but occasionally the error comes back after reimaging the machines which is quite frustrating. I'll look into the symantec fix though!

Comment: reimaging? Are you cloning or doing like a full sysprep'd and generalised image?

Comment: I've met so many people who just do a full clone of machines, not realising the whole importance of SID relations with Active Directory etc.

Comment: they are thin clients so you pop a flash drive in and it just takes it and my coworker thinks that the SID relations are getting corrupted some how.